# Dynamically invoking Soap Service Methods

Tags: c#, wsdl

I am trying to write some C# (.NET Framework 4.7.1) that takes in a WSDL and then returns Meta, method signatures and any complex types defined in WSDL. This Meta Data can then be used to invoke any method. My current thought is to use these two Namespaces.

```
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Web.Services.Description;
```

Depending on whether its an older .ASMX type service or a newer WCF style one, with Bindings etc. Akin to "Adding Web Reference" or "Adding Service Reference" in Visual Studio. I generate C# code then Compile to a DLL using Roslyn. I get the Meta data using reflection. Found this easier than reverse engineering the WSDL. The idea then is to invoke methods using reflection.

The trouble is, for WCF style services I cannot get the Binding information I need to pass into the Client Constructor

```
        System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription serviceDescription = null;
        Uri address = new Uri(wsdl);
        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
        MetadataExchangeClient metadataExchangeClient = new MetadataExchangeClient(binding);
        metadataExchangeClient.ResolveMetadataReferences = true;

        MetadataSet ms = metadataExchangeClient.GetMetadata(address, MetadataExchangeClientMode.HttpGet);
        Collection<MetadataSection> documentCollection = ms.MetadataSections;

        if (documentCollection != null && documentCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            serviceDescription = (System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription)documentCollection[0].Metadata;
        }
```

The above code is used to get MetaSections but these are ServiceDescriptions from this namespace System.Web.Services.Description. Which then contains Bindings and operations etc. But I need Binding from this namespace System.ServiceModel.Description to pass into this constructor so I can then invoke methods

```
public Service1Client(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
        base(binding, remoteAddress) {
}
```

If anyone has any pointers it would be really helpful. Thank you

Comment: Found solution. I take the MetaDataSet and use to Instantiate a WsdlImporter

Comment: WsdlImporter wsdlImporter = new WsdlImporter(metadataSet);

            var bindings = wsdlImporter.ImportAllBindings();
            var endpoints = wsdlImporter.ImportAllEndpoints();